# (vulgar) writings on my wall

Tags: значення-слів, орфографія

A person left two words written in red color on my bedoom wall. I could read the second one as боягуз all right. but I could not parse the first (upper) one. maybe it is misspelled. suykyn? scykyn? I infer from the context that it may be derogatory, or is it an adjective, like a special kind of coward?

[image: words on wall]

Comment: Welcome to Ukrainian Language! Like other language sites on Stack Exchange, we [do not translate](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22652/59219) texts or words, so this question may be closed as off-topic. The first word is, indeed, misspelled. It should be *сцикун*, a derogatory for "coward", literally "one who pisses".

Comment: I can read and understand written Ukrainian quite well, so I'm fine with an answer in Ukrainian, will try to find a better tag

Comment: Your thoughts about misspelled is right; correct word could be mentioned сцикун (synonym for боягуз) or next derogatory non-correct сукин (bitch's < originally female-dog) < (correct) сучин, which is often with another word, сучин or (adj) сучий [word].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like misspelling of *[сцику́н](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/57687-scykun.html#show_point)* (stsykun).

This derives from *[сця́ти](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/57692-scjaty.html#show_point)* (stsiaty) with meaning "to pee" and, figuratively, "to fear" ("to fear to the extent of losing control of own urine"). Hereof *сцикло́*, *сцику́н* and etc are figurative for "coward" (literally — "one who piss"). (When I started to write this answer, I assumed *сцяти* to be a modern word of Russian origin, but it appeared to be in fact from Proto-Slavic *[sьcati/sьkati](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/s%D1%8Ccati)*.)

Not to be confused with *[сса́ти](http://sum.in.ua/s/ssaty)* (ssaty) and *[сца́ти](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/57682-scaty.html)* (stsaty) with meaning "to suck". As the verb *to suck* has negative meanings in English, you might wrongly assume it has similar ones in Ukrainian (and somehow build associative chains between milk sucking and fear) — but in fact historically the verb *to suck* in Ukrainian doesn't have such connotation as in English (though due to the growing influence of the latter it may get in future). We have a word *ссаве́ць* ("one who sucks"), which means just "mammal", a proverb *ласкаве теля двох маток ссе* (literally — "gentle calf sucks two mothers"; in English more often expressed as *the humblest calf sucks the most milk*), which uses *to suck* rather in positive meaning, and etc. So the offense word *сцикун* is from "to pee", not from "to suck".

Comment: -1: a substantial part of this post has nothing to do with the original question and only confuses a reader.

Comment: @bytebuster we just need to edit the answer with an additional note like "extra info:" no need to put too many minuses here.

Comment: учнем української мови, я ціную додаткову інформацію. так і можуть інши люди.